# How to build the Lagrange function when variable contain same part?

Tags: optimization

Recently, I encoutered the following objective function

$$
\text{minimize}\quad \mathbf E(\mathbf X)=\mathbf X^{\text T}\mathbf K \mathbf X\\
\text{s.t.} \quad\mathbf A\mathbf X=\mathbf P
$$

where

$\mathbf X=[x_0,\cdots,x_{\hat n+p}]^{\text T}\leftarrow\color{red}{\text{unknown}}\\
\mathbf K=(k_{i,j})_{(\hat n+p+1)\times (\hat n+p+1)}\leftarrow \color{red}{\text{known }} \text{symmetric stiffness matrix}\\
\mathbf A=(a_{i,j})_{(n+1)\times (\hat n+p+1)}\leftarrow\color{red}{\text{known }} \text{coefficient matrix}\\
\mathbf P=[p_0,\cdots,p_{n}]^{\text T}\leftarrow \color{red}{\text{known }}$

Here "**unknown**" dneotes "unknown variable", while "**known**" denotes "known parameters"

When the unknown variables $\mathbf X$ is different, I can use the Lagrange multiplier as follows:

(1)define the Lagrange function
$$
\mathbf L(\mathbf X,\mathbf v)=\mathbf X^{\text T}\mathbf K \mathbf X+2\mathbf v^{\text T}(\mathbf A\mathbf X-\mathbf P)\\
\mathbf v=[v_0,\cdots,v_{\hat n+p+1}]
$$
(2)calculate the partial derivative with respect $\mathbf X$ and $\mathbf v$

$$
\begin{cases}
\Large{\frac{\partial \mathbf L}{\partial \mathbf X}}\normalsize=(\mathbf K+\mathbf K^{\text T})\mathbf X+2\mathbf A \mathbf v^{\text T}\leftarrow(\mathbf K=\mathbf K^{\text T})\\
\Large{\frac{\partial \mathbf L}{\partial \mathbf v}}=\normalsize 2(\mathbf A \mathbf X-\mathbf P)\\
\end{cases}
$$
Then let 
$$
\frac {\partial \mathbf L}{\partial \mathbf X}=\mathbf O\\
\frac {\partial \mathbf L}{\partial \mathbf v}=\mathbf O\\
$$

I can achieve the below **block matrix** linear system
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\mathbf K & \mathbf A^{\text{T}}\\
\mathbf A & \mathbf O
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\mathbf X\\
\mathbf v
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
\mathbf O\\
\mathbf P
\end{pmatrix}
$$

where, $\mathbf O$ denotes zero matrix/vector.

However, when the unknown variable $\mathbf X$ has same part. That is, for the $\mathbf X=[x_0,\cdots,x_{\hat n},x_{\hat n+1},\cdots,x_{\hat n+p}]^{\text T}$

$$x_{\hat n+i}=x_{i-1}\qquad i=1,2,\cdots,p$$

For this case, I just need introduce $\hat n+1$ Lagrange multiplier. Namely,

$$\mathbf v=[v_0,\cdots,v_{\hat n}]^{\text T}$$

But I don't know how to build **Lagrange** function. Could someone give me some suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: known vs. unknown is typically expressed as parameter vs. variable

Answer (score 1):

You add $\sum_{i=0}^{\hat{n}}v_i(x_{\hat{n}+1}-x_{i-1})$ to the Lagrangian.

As for your current Lagrangian, the factor 2 is unusual.

Comment: you write the constraint in matrix form first :)